# Draw a rectangle around image

Tags: java, image, graphics

I want to draw a rectangle around BufferedImage so it will create a border like frame.

So I load 2 BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage a = ImageIO.read(new File(aPath));
BufferedImage b = ImageIO.read(new File(bPath));
```

And send it for drawing:

```
private void drawImageBorder(BufferedImage imageWithoutBorder) {

    Graphics2D graph = imageWithoutBorder.createGraphics();
    graph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    //create a black Rectangle - 1px bigger the original image
    graph.fill(new Rectangle(imageWithoutBorder.getMinX(), imageWithoutBorder.getMinY(), imageWithoutBorder.getWidth() + 1, imageWithoutBorder.getHeight() +1));
    //draw the image inside it
    graph.drawImage(imageWithoutBorder, 0, 0, null);
    graph.dispose();
}
```

For some reason it does nothing, there are similer questions like [drawing-filled-rectangle-over-a-bufferedimage](http://drawing-filled-rectangle-over-a-bufferedimage) but I could not finnd helpful answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost right, but for the enlarged size and positioning.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = Image.getHeight();
int border = 1;

BufferedImage framedImage = new BufferedImage(w + 2*border, h + 2*border, image.getType());

Graphics2D graph = framedImage.createGraphics();
graph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graph.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, w + 2*border, h + 2*border));
graph.drawImage(image, border, border, null);
graph.dispose();
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Comment: Well I have tested it and it does nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Try Setting `border` to 4 for ease of detection (in/exclusive rect boundary), and write framedImage to a new file with ImageIO.write.

Comment: I doubt you want fill. I suggest trying draw or drawRect instead ;)

Comment: @Terje as I made the border thicknes as (changeable) variable I was simply lazy for the frame code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason can be, that you don't persist the changes made to the image, for example writing them back into an image file with ImageIO.write.